Memory Interfacing of 8086
I'm finding trouble doing this exercise from a course I'm taking:
Interface 4 RAM's of 64 kB and 4 ROM's of 64 kB, both of which have 2 active low Chip Enable inputs. Also, the circuit has to be done with complete decoding knowing that DS=4000h and we want to execute the instruction "mov [0010h], AX". Use a 74xxx138 decoder.
I've done many exercises where we only have 2 chips, but for 4 the method doesn't apply. How can I do the memory mapping?

I assume your RAMs and ROMs are 8-bits (1 byte) wide?  And that you have 8 chips total attached to the address and 16-bit data bus?

You have a 3 to 8 decoder to decode the address and 2 banks of 16 bit RAM and ROM.

It should be doable. But first you need to figure out if KB means kilobits or kilobytes. And what other assumptions should be made about the system, like where the executed instruction is and how it ended up there. Also putting all RAM to address DS=4000h may not make sense in real life if you want to use interrupts and catch exceptions like divide by zero. But we can ignore that as the assignment may not care about it.

Yes, it is 1 byte wide

You only have to select 1 of 4 things - 1 of 2 SRAM banks or 1 of 2 ROM banks,  So you only need half of a '138.  This is because you concatenate 2 SRAMS or 2 ROMS to create a 2-byte wide (16 bits) memory structure, which then connects to the 16 bit data bus of the 8086,
